# Square roots with composite modulus

Tags: number-theory

How can I find $x$ that for given $a$ and composite $n$ satisfies the expression below?

$$x^2 = a \mod n$$

In my particular case $n=2^{32}$:

$$x^2 = a \mod 2^{32}$$

Mathematica comes with nice `PowerMod` function that takes also fractional arguments, which solves the problem above. What I'd like is to implement this function in my program.

---

I found somewhere people recommending the use of Euler's totient function like this:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x^k &=& a &\mod m \\
uk &=& 1 &\mod \phi(m) \\
u &=& k^{-1} &\mod \phi(m) \\
x &=& a^u &\mod m
\end{eqnarray}
$$
but apparently in this case it can't work because as far as I know, $u$ does not exist (which is probably because $k=2$ and $n=\phi(2^{32})=2^{31}$ are not coprime). I've also seen people mentioning Hensel lifting but I don't fully understand this technique.

Comment: See e.g. the section _Powers of 2_ in John  Cook's text **Solving quadratic congruences** at http://www.johndcook.com/quadratic_congruences.html.
Another source is section _The Congruence x^ = a (mod 2^k)_ in 
A. Adler, J.E. Coury: The Theory of Numbers. 

And there is Algorithm A.2.6 **Finding Square Roots Modulo a Power of 2** in 
IEEE P1363 Standard Specifications for Public Key Cryptography (not free, but some early drafts are available, search for _p1363 draft_)